# How to get a field with a certain amount of sub-field in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't think i phrased the question correctly. I am trying to grab all the GroupID fields from a table that have more then 6 UserID fields:

Here's what my table "group_members" looks like

```
|  GroupID  |  UserID  |  role  |
_________________________________

|  22       |  02      |  role  |
|  22       |  03      |  role  |
|  25       |  01      |  role  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from group_members
group by GroupID
having count(*) >6
```

Comment: This will show not only `UserID` but all fields of the table. It will also not show correct results if there are rows where `UserID` is `NULL`.

Comment: @ypercube: I think you lost here. If this show all fields what's the problem. One user can be in only one group and this is a table to hold the relation between group and users. So there is no group with `null user id`. Your down vote is worthless here

Comment: -1, I agree with Ypercube, what's the use of selecting a random user_id and role?

Comment: @Joha: Explain what do you mean by _random user_id and role_? I think you are misunderstanding too. This is very clear this table is to hold the `user-group relationship`  and there is no row with user id as `null` and also there is no two or more identical rows with `user_id`

Comment: @Shakti, if one user can only be in one group it would be useless to have this table, you could just store **that** data in the user table, so it is logical to assume that one user can be a member of more than one group. Your conclusion might be based on the 3 rows shown, but not grounded in logic IMHO.

Comment: @Johan: This is not true, People generally prefer to create new table. I am not talking based on posted data and I am sure about this

Comment: @Shakti: You are right in one point: That (very probably) the `UserID` is not Null, as the table is (very probably again) an association table between Users and Groups. But again, very probably is not sure. Perhaps this is just a view and in that case it may very well contain Nulls.

Comment: On the *'random userid and role'* issue, you are dead wrong. Your query will return, for every group, ONE userid and ONE role (from more than 6 userid and more than 6 roles). So, it is safely assumed to be a random userid from the 6+ possible. It's usually useless to have that.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting all `GroupID` that have more than 6 `UserID`, or in other words `GroupID` that appear in 6 rows (and the `UserID`s are not `NULL`):

```
SELECT GroupID
FROM group_members
GROUP BY GroupID
HAVING COUNT(UserID) > 6
```

Selecting all `GroupID` that have more than 6 **DISTINCT** `UserID`s :

```
SELECT GroupID
FROM group_members
GROUP BY GroupID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) > 6
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a GROUP BY and HAVING statement in your SQL. Also note, that the UserID column must be a number data-type (there are many variants, but in your case in your case probably an integer)

the SQL:

```
select GroupID 
FROM group_members
GROUP BY GroupID
HAVING count(*) >6
```

more info on group by statement: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp
more info on having statement: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: Why does `UserID` has to be a number data type?

Comment: note that w3schools is **not** a good resource. W3schools is known for giving wrong, horribly out-of-date, and Internet Explorer-specific advice. (It has no connection with the W3C.)
It is one of the more complete reference websites, but anything you learn there should be checked elsewhere. Check out http://www.w3fools.com for a list of reasons why it's not a good resource.